# Can't login into Magento 2 admin xampp

Tags: magento2, admin-login, xampp

I cannot login to Magento 2 admin due to the fact it is installed on 127.0.0.1:8080. This is an imported site and **not** a fresh install.

I have changed cookie domains to reflect the correct paths but still no admin access.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: changed base URLs?

Comment: yes thats what i find really weird ive changed everything i can think of

Comment: is the login pop up there for admin login? Or 404? do you get error when trying to log in?

Comment: You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.

is the error message i get when login in

Comment: did you check the database connection?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal how do you mean, i dont understand can you give me more details about check db connection just to make sure im not missing anything

Comment: to avoid any issues like this one, create proper virual host, add domain name and check if your session is properly written and read. looks like session is lost, magento creates new session everytime you click login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new user:

```
bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="testing" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="testing@example.com" --admin-firstname="Test" --admin-lastname="Test"
```

When you get the error:

> No Administrators role was found, data fixture needs to be run

Follow this link for more info: https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/how-to-create-admin-user-in-magento-2-via-command-line

As a **quick** fix:

You need to delete value from this table `core_config_data`:

```
web/cookie/cookie_domain
web/cookie/cookie_httponly
web/cookie/cookie_lifetime
web/cookie/cookie_path
```

Comment: [Exception]
  No Administrators role was found, data fixture needs to be run

Comment: https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/how-to-create-admin-user-in-magento-2-via-command-line have a read. I think it might be that your role name has changed.

Comment: my role name is admin

Comment: check the quick fix i posted in my answer to see if that works

Comment: i had to edit the adminaccount.php and add a new user but i am now in thanks

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, since I did a data strip with `magerun2`. The data from this table: `authorization_role` was also erased.

This query fixed it:

```
INSERT INTO authorization_role (role_id, parent_id, tree_level, sort_order, role_type, user_id, user_type, role_name) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, '2', 'Administrators');
```

More details, here: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2/issues/351

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your account is locked, try unlock by command prompt. open cmd got to you magento directory root and type the following command.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock <username>
```

username will be your user name of account. it will be like

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin
```

Comment: nope unlocked and still the same

Comment: in magento 2 it always show that your account is locked when you type wrong password. try create new admin by following command
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin" change new admin username , passowrd and email

Answer (score 0):

Probably the *authorization_role* table is empty.

https://www.it-rem.ru/magento-2-exception-no-administrators-role-was-found-data-fixture-needs-to-be-run.html

Answer (score 0):

**For Imported site,check the following things,** 
1). remove the cookie domain and cookie path

> web/cookie/cookie_domain
> web/cookie/cookie_path

2). Disable the Two Factor Authentication

> bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

3). Create new user

> php bin/magento admin:user:create